# Tagfield bugs in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created a very little fiddle [demo](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m93), which demonstartes two nasty bugs of the tagfield component. One bug can be observed in FireFox and another bug in Chrome. In Chrome you would see a terrible looking vertical scroller:

[image]

And in FireFox you can see, that if you select both values (there are two in the store, and then remove the second value from the selection, then the tagfield still holds focus on the second row, and so the value is not visible:

[image]

I hope, that all these bugs are not bugs, but some misconfiguration. And I hope, somebody can provide those properties, that should be configured to fix it.

**CODE**

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag',{
            renderTo: "tagfield",
            displayField: "name",
            valueField: "id",
            queryMode: 'local',
            autocomplete: 'off',
            grow: false,
            triggerOnClick: false,
            itemId: "BaseLayers",
            forceSelection: true,
            width: 200,
            matchFieldWidth: false,
            value: 1,
            store: {
                autoLoad: true,
                storeId: "BaseLayersStore",
                fields:[
                    {name:'id', type:'string'},
                    {name:'name', type:'string'}
                ],
                data: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: "Very first value"
                },{
                    id: 2,
                    name: "Second value"
                }]
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure, if it is possible to insert ExtJS code here. I've never done that

Comment: I get a list of errors, when I try to do that. So, probably, the fiddle, that I provided, would be enough.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder providing the Sencha ExtJS Fiddle is better than the Stack Snippets. In there you can switch easily between multiple versions and latest versions are available. The cdnjs has only GPL version 6.2.0

Comment: @Jacobian And how do you want tag field to behave ? Should it expand as in the examples? Without the scroller ? As in the examples? http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#form-tag

Comment: @pagep: I agree, but only because it appears that you can't use ExtJS in Stack Snippets because of the way they're sandboxed. That's fine. As long as the code is in the question (which it is now), that's good *enough*. Runnable on-site would be better, but would seem not to be feasible.

Comment: @pagep. First of all, I need it not to grow, because it breaks the layout of my application. Second, I need it to scroll to the visible selected value, if it exists, and not to scroll to the row below this visible value. In other words, I just need it to behave like an old good combobox with multiSelect set to true.

Comment: @Jacobian yep I really miss the old good combobox with multiSelect too. I never had too much items in the tagfield so I usually set the dimensions of the tagfield bigger, so they can fit most of the items or I use the grow :\

Answer (score 1):

you can use **grow:true** config if you don't want vertical scroll.
please check fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1m9v

```
Ext.application({
name : 'Fiddle',

launch : function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.form.field.Tag',{
        renderTo: "tagfield",
        displayField: "name",
        valueField: "id",
        queryMode: 'local',
        autocomplete: 'off',
        grow: false,
        triggerOnClick: false,
        itemId: "BaseLayers",
        forceSelection: true,
        width: 200,
        grow:true,
        matchFieldWidth: false,
        value: 1,
        store: {
            autoLoad: true,
            storeId: "BaseLayersStore",
            fields:[
                {name:'id', type:'string'},
                {name:'name', type:'string'}
            ],
            data: [{
                id: 1,
                name: "Very first value"
            },{
                id: 2,
                name: "Second value"
            }]
        }
    })
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But as I said in my comment, I do not want it to grow. Because, when it grows, it breaks the whole layout of my application

Comment: In that case you can customize your vertical scroller design so that it looks good ...beacuse vertical scroller is the only way you can see your rest of records which are hide.

Comment: You could use `growMax` to limit how much it can grow as a compromise between showing the scroller when the user selects a lot of items and having the tagField using up space when fewer items are selected.